# Unable to decode POST JSON object in PHP

Tags: php, json, post

I send POST request with JSON string in JSP to PHP but the received JSON cannot be decoded.

Here is my html file:

```
<html><body>

<form name="frm" method=post action="http://www.test.com/get_json.php">

<input type=hidden id=test name=test>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</BODY></HTML>

<script>
var jsonObj = {
            "merchID": "0000", 
            "amount": "test"
        };

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
document.getElementById('test').value = jsonString;
</script>
```

Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    echo $data['amount'];
?>
```

The output of **echo file_get_contents("php://input");** is

> DO=%7B%22merchID%22%3A%220000%22%2C%22amount%22%3A%22test%22%7D

which means the JSON objecy has been successfully received.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not sending a request with a pure JSON request body, you're sending a regular url-encoded form request. As your output shows, the request body contains the JSON string *inside* a form-encoded string. You need to first URL-decode that and then pick your JSON string from it. Fortunately PHP has already done that for you and the data is available inside `$_POST`:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['DO']);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I tried that but it shows nothing.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`. There's a discrepancy between what your form says the field should be called and what your output says; I don't know what is correct in your *actual* code.

Comment: The corresponding output is `array(1) { ["DO"]=> string(34) "{"merchID":"0000","amount":"test"}" }` so it should be $_POST['DO']

Comment: if the name attribute is "test", it would be in $_POST['test'], not in $_POST['do']  ...

Comment: Solved with @deceze code and with `echo $data->amount;`

Answer (score 0):

when you don't specify the enctype attribute on a `<form method=post` which doesn't contain any file uploads, it defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-encoding, when php receive an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-encoded POST request, it parses the request and put the data in the `$_POST` variable, because your element containing the javascript had the name "test", your json ends up in the variable `$_POST['test']`, thus this should work: 
`json_decode($_POST['test']);`  - a reason for `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` not working, include the fact that the data in php://input  is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-encoded, NOT json-encoded. given that PHP has already decoded it for you in the $_POST variable, you don't need to decode that manually, but if you for some reason would WANT to do so, php has the `parse_str` function to decode `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-encoded data, so you could do this too:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$data);
$data=$data['test'];
$data=json_decode($data);
```